# xml parsing error xml or text declaration not at start of entity in wordpress feed

Tags: wordpress, rss

i'm getting following error in my wordpress site,

```
XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: http://www.domain.com/news/feed/rss/
Line Number 3, Column 3:        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="0.92">
----------------^
```

i have tried almost all solutions found via google, also tried the answers of same questions here in stackoverflow, but still i'm getting this error.

do any one have any idea about how to come out of it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing [fix-rss-feed](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fix-rss-feed/) plugin.

Also I think you have a space before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Getting rid of it should do the trick.

Comment: I think the plugin mentioned is outdated. You can try this plugin instead: https://wordpress.org/plugins/fix-my-feed-rss-repair/

Answer (score 0):

fix-rss-feed plugin is outdated. I had the same problem with the RSS feeds, try the solution provided here http://wejn.org/stuff/wejnswpwhitespacefix.php.html it works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, rather than using a plugin, a better solution would be to remove all trailing white space across all PHP files in your theme directory. In a terminal window run:

```
cd yoursite/wp-content/themes/yourtheme
```

then run

```
find ./ -name "*.php" -exec sed -i -e '/^\n*$/d' {} \;
```

After that runs, try navigating to `yoursite.com/feed`